# Как правильно сделать контроллеры? ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, маршрутизация, controller

Есть контроллер с маршрутом

> api/books

Я хочу сделать метод для получения вообще всех книг, делаю его так:

```
[HttpGet()]
        public IActionResult GetBooks()
        {
            try
            {
                var books = booksService.GetAllBooks();
                return Ok(books);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error. Cannot get list of books.");
            }
        }
```

И мне нужно сделать поиск книг по авторам. Делать **вот так** не очень хорошая практика:

```
[HttpGet("findbyname/{author}")]
        public IActionResult GetBooksByAuthorName(string author)
        {
            try
            {
                var books = booksService.GetBooksByAuthorName(author);

                if (books== null || books.Count() < 1)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    return Ok(books);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
            }
        }
```

Тогда запросы буду типа того

> /api/books/findbyauthor/rowling

И я нашел такую штуку, как **QueryString**, попробовал сделать метод:

```
public IActionResult GetBooksByAuthorName([FromQuery(Name = "author")] string author)
        {
            try
            {
                var books = booksService.GetBooksByAuthorName(author);

                if (books == null || books.Count() < 1)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    return Ok(books);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
            }
        }
```

Но постменом он не ловится, т.к. конфликтирует с получением вообще всех книг. Как решить данную проблему? Сделать **FromQuery** в начальном get-е и проверять его на null?

**UPD:** Я хочу, чтобы у меня такой запрос возвращал все книги

> api/books/

А такой запрос должен возвращать только книги по автору

> api/books/?author=rowling

Answer (score 0):

```
// GET: api/book
// GET: api/book/{author}
[HttpGet()]
[HttpGet("{author}")]
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery(Name = "author")] string author)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(author))
   {
      // Ищем по автору
   }
   else 
   {
      // Вытягиваем все
   }
}
```

Лучше чтобы у вас в бизнес логике был метод, который бы вытаскивал данные по фильру. Например:

```
//FilterBook.cs

public class FilterBook
{
  public string AuthorEqual {get;set;}
}
```

// BLL: bookService.cs
...

```
public IEnumerable<Book> Find(FilterBook filter = null)
{
   if (filter == null)
   {
      // Выбираем все
   }
   else 
   {
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.AuthorEqual))
       {
           // Отбираем только по автору
       }
       ...
   }
}
```

И после вы сможете использовать данный сервис в своем контроллере...так же могут быть другие параметры фильтра. Еще плюсом будет то, что этот самый фильтр вы сможете передавать 
непосредственно с клиента.

Comment: Сделал пока так, скорее всего это говнокод: [код на pastebin](https://pastebin.com/510EnvH6)